# How to generate a proxy for asmx service Dynamically

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, asmx

I need to create a proxy for a `ASMX service`, given by a third party dynamically so that I will able to change the service url at runtime

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @PaulZahra i have done it earlier for WCF services using channel factory, but not sure of ASMX

Comment: This is for sql server reporting services but might steer you in the right direction for generating the proxy class... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: This class provides that functionality.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionimporter?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0